# Making sure to type in the right password on the right place

Tags: password-policy, defense, separation

This is not about technology, but about human factors.

I type in passwords so often, that it is a habit that doesn't require thinking. I type these fast and correct.
Lets take an SSH  agent password as an example. I login to the computer, then I unlock my ssh key before I start working.

Now I am working at different computers for different stuff (like work, private, projects) with similar workflows. Sometimes I notice, after the second wrong attempt, I  used the password from another workplace, so I can login on the third try.

Now the problem is that if I suspect one of the computer to be insecure, maybe the first two tries were already captured by a keylogger or a ssh-agent version with backdoor, which logs the passwords into a file.

What is the best way to mentally separate different workspaces? In firefox I use different themes for example, which help me remember even in the subconscious, at which project I am working and what credentials I should use there and what projects need to be separated. With a lot of other programs this isn't that easy.

Comment: what about colors? each color is assigned to a workspace, which helps you identify quickly in which workspace you are. In a terminal you can easily put colors for the prompt, and for a GUI you could modify the theme of your desktop environment. For example, [QubeOS](https://www.qubes-os.org/) is doing that for their different VMs.

Comment: This is an option for firefox, thunderbird and the bash prompt. But for example the pinentry program just looks the same, login managers (console or gui) are started before your custom theme takes effect, and so on. It's exactly the flows which make you work efficiently, which can lead to disclosing information which is meant to another system, when not being super cautious, like always pausing and thinking about the prompt before entering something.

Comment: You can modify your login manager to change its overall color, and maybe use distinct sound when the login page is available and different for each workspace. Regarding your desktop environment, I don't necessarily mean the window of a program, but maybe the color of the taskbar (or equivalent).

Comment: You're thinking of me as an admin. This is of course possible at my home pc. On other pcs i need to take care, without being able to modify a lot. There are some existing features, like the ubuntu desktop manager showing the unity background image (if configured to do so), but most stuff just presents it default appearance.

Comment: You are right. Maybe, you could modify the theme of the physical workspace itself, instead of the virtual one. Put some stickers of different colors at each workstation (e.g. on the screen and the keyboard) or any item that you must see before typing or looking at the screen (e.g. put a piece of colored paper that you must remove from the screen with a word describing the workstation). Not sure if this would qualify as an answer, it is just some ideas, so I prefer to keep it as a comment.